# Nuxtjs nuxt-link is not showing as pointer on hover

Tags: css, vue.js, hyperlink, nuxt.js

I have `nuxt-link` like this

```
<nuxt-link to="/login" class="nuxtLinkStyle">Login</nuxt-link>
```

And class `nuxtLinkStyle` to style it

```
.nuxtLinkStyle {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: inherit !important;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

But on hovering over the link cursor does not show pointer but default. Any tips how to do this?

Comment: It works. Check "computed styles" in Dev Tools - maybe you have some other rules colliding....

Comment: @MichalLevý In computed styles I see it as pointer . but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you share a fiddle?